# problem display grouped boxplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have problem with my grouped boxplot, they are not display as boxplot, i can't understand why.
This is what i did:

```
library(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

data <- read.table(args[1], header=T, sep="\t")
data.m <- melt(data, id.var = "dijarn")

ggplot(data = data.m, aes(x=dijarn, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable))
```

exemple of my data :

```
> head(data.m)
     dijarn variable    value
1 dijarn043   ATP5PB 2230.746
2 dijarn044   ATP5PB 2501.788
3 dijarn045   ATP5PB 2067.263
4 dijarn046   ATP5PB 4060.777
5 dijarn047   ATP5PB 3075.087
6 dijarn048   ATP5PB 2892.501
```

i have 37 dijarn and here 5 variable.
then it's a lot but i think ggplot2 can handle it ?

[image]

i tried to chance size of my image but i didn't change anything. did i forget some option ?
thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one value of "value" for each value of "dijarn". In the data you show it looks like "dijarn" is unique and you can't make a boxplot from a single point. It's not clear what you are trying to plot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create 5 boxplots one for each level of the variable or 37 boxplots one for each level of dijarn?  You can't create a boxplot of one observation. Boxplots reflect the IQR (quartiles of a range)

try factoring the variable you want a boxplot on

`data$dijarn <- as.factor(data$dijarn)`